# ¿Como usar async/await con firestore?

Tags: javascript, firebase, async-await

Verán cree un sistema de archivos con `firebase/firestore` y `firebase/storage` basado en promesas usando `async/await`, el sistema de subida de archivos y registro funciona muy bien pero el problema ocurre al verificar si el archivo ya existe en el registro, y si existe se rechaza la promesa con un `throw new Error('This file already exists')`.

Pero la consola me tira este error:

> `<unknown>` non-error promise rejection captured

Lo que hago es guardar todos los registros en un sólo documento, para eso obtengo los datos del documento y los concatenó con el nuevo objeto creando un array de objetos nuevo, para así guardarlo en dicho documento, ya que sino lo hago así solo se registra el objeto nuevo.

Este es mi código:

```
import _ from 'lodash'
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app'
// Más módulos de firebase aquí...
class Upload {
  constructor() {
    this.config = { /* keys access */ }
    this.init()
  }
  init() {
   if (!firebase.apps.length) {
      firebase.initializeApp(this.config)
    }
  }
  doc(doc) {
    return firebase.firestore().doc(doc)
  }
  async get() {
    var res = await this.doc('upload/files').get()
    return res.data()
  }
  async set(data) {
    var res = await this.get()
    var exists = _.find(res.files, file => file.name === data.name) !== undefined
    if (exists) {
      throw new Error('This file already exists')
    }
    var files = _.concat(res.files, data)
    if (typeof data === 'object') {
      return this.doc('upload/files').update({
       files
     }) // retorna un promesa
    }
  }
}

var upload = new Upload();
upload.set({
  file: 'md5.jpg',
  name: 'original_filename.jpg',
  size: 1234567
})
.then(() => console.log('Upload complete'))
.catch(() => console.log('Error'));
```

Ese es el único código que me da error lo demás funciona correctamente.

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que capturar el error en un `try/catch`

```
async set(data) {
    try {
        var res = await this.get()
        var exists = _.find(res.files, file => file.name === data.name) !== undefined
        if (exists) {
        throw new Error('This file already exists')
        }
        var files = _.concat(res.files, data)
        if (typeof data === 'object') {
            return this.doc('upload/files').update({
                files
            }) // retorna un promesa
        }
    } catch(e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: De echo lo intente de ese modo, pero cambiando el `console.log` por un `throw new Error('...')` pero me sigue dando el mismo error

Comment: Si vuelves a lanzar el error pues lo tienes que capturar en algun  momento en tu código. Puedes añadir el try/catch en donde hagas `upload.set(data) ` .

Comment: Lo se, pero habló del error `<unknown> non-error promise rejection captured`. A pesar de que uso `upload.set(data).catch((e) => console.log(e.toString()))` me sigue saliendo ese error `<unknown> non-error promise rejection captured `

Comment: También me sale como `unhandledrejection: This file already exists`

Comment: Ahh perdon no vi que hacias el catch. Y las llamadas del `get` y `doc` te funcionan bien? Puedes mirar en dev tools la tab de network para ver si alguna falla.